# How to make list of twisted deferred operations truly async

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am new to using Twisted library, I want to make a list of operations async. Take example of the following pseudo code:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def getDataAsync(host):
    data = yield AsyncHttpAPI(host) # some asyc api which returns deferred
    return data
    
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def funcPrintData():
    hosts = []; # some list of hosts, say 1000 in number
    for host in hosts:
        data = yield getDataAsync(host)
        # why doesn't the following line get printed as soon as first result is available
        # it waits for all getDataAsync to be queued before calling the callback and so print data
        print(data)
```

Please comment if the question is not clear. Is there a better way of doing this? Should I instead be using the DeferredList ?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
data = yield getDataAsync(host)
```

means "stop running this function until the `getDataAsync(host)` operation has completed.  If the function stops running, the `for` loop can't get to any subsequent iterations so those operations can't even begin until after the first `getDataAsync(host)` has completed.  If you want to run everything concurrently then you need to *not* stop running the function until all of the operations have started.  For example:

```
ops = []
for host in hosts:
    ops.append(getDataAsync(host))
```

After this runs, all of the operations will have started regardless of whether or not any have finished.

What you do with `ops` depends on whether you want results in the same order as `hosts` or if you want them all at once when they're all ready or if you want them one at a time in the order the operations succeed.

`DeferredList` is for getting them all at once when they're all ready as a list in the same order as the input list (`ops`):

```
datas = yield DeferredList(ops)
```

If you want to process each result as it becomes available, it's easier to use `addCallback`:

```
ops = []
for host in hosts:
    ops.append(getDataAsync(host).addCallback(print))
```

This still doesn't `yield` so the whole group of operations are started.  However, the callback on each operation runs as soon as that operation has a result.  You're still left with a list of `Deferred` instances in `ops` which you can still use to wait for all of the results to finish if you want or attach overall error handling to (at least one of those is a good idea otherwise you have dangling operations that you can't easily account for in callers of `funcPrintDat`).

Comment: Thanks for answer, as I mentioned the number of hosts are in thousands, how can I limit the number of concurrent calls, so that I don't run into timeout/ConnectionDone kind of issue. I want to start let' say 100 concurrent operations, and then if any one is completed, I want to add another operation in the list and so on.

Comment: Perhaps something like https://as.ynchrono.us/2006/05/limiting-parallelism_22.html